# Get array with another array indexing with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

```
arr_1 = np.array([5, 1, 6, 3, 3, 10, 3, 6, 12])
arr_2 = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
arr_idx_num_3 = np.where(arr_1 == 3)[0]
print(arr_idx_num_3)  ## [3 4 6]
```

#how to i get this array Numpy with "arr_idx_num_3"

```
arr_2 = [40 50 70]
```

Comment: `arr_2[arr_1 == 3]` also works if both arrays are guaranteed to be the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use it like:

```
print(arr_2[arr_idx_num_3])
```

output:

```
>>> [40 50 70]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop should do the trick.

```py
import numpy as np

arr_1 = np.array([5, 1, 6, 3, 3, 10, 3, 6, 12])
arr_2 = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])


idx_num = 3
arr_idx_num = []
for i in range(len(arr_1)):
    if arr_1[i] == idx_num:
        arr_idx_num.append(arr_2[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

```
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(arr_1) if x == 3]
arr_2[indices]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
  
arr_1 = np.array([5, 1, 6, 3, 3, 10, 3, 6, 12])
arr_2 = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])

arr_idx_num_3 = np.nonzero(arr_1==3)
print(arr_2[arr_idx_num_3])
```